Does something necessarily come from nothing?
Throughout the history of time, it has been almost everyone’s intuition that something cannot come from nothing. That intuition is so strong that many can’t even imagine this to be false.
But wouldn’t the infinite regress of explanation make this necessarily true? If B explains A, what explains B? If C explains B, what explains C? If this can’t continue forever, then C would exist unexplained.
But if C exists without explanation, doesn’t that mean C comes from nothing? I wager that many people believe that something exists without explanation but not that something comes from nothing. Why?
Possible responses to this: some things may be eternal and have “always existed”. But that just leads to the same problem with infinite regress with respect to time (I.e. an infinite past may not be possible). But even if something could be eternal, isn’t it still coming from nothing in that nothing caused it to exist…it just exists and that’s it. What’s the difference between this and something just “coming to exist”?

Existing without explanation and coming from nothing are two different things. If a soccer ball suddenly reshaped into a cube for no reason that cube will exist without explanation. But it did not come from nothing.

So far such a thing has not been observed, and there doesn't seem to be any reason to believe that things were so different in the past as to allow it.  OTOH, we can only see so far into the past, so I suppose one might speculate many things.  Nothingness is one of infinite options, so, I guess you can pick your favorite.

First, you need to precisely define the words something and nothing. Is energy nothing? Is stress in the structure of spacetime nothing?  Is something we don't have a theory for yet nothing? "Nothing we understand" is a better defined term, but is not an absolute nothing. Nihil ex nihil is certainly a human preference, but begs the question.

rara avis in terris nigroque simillima cygno
First, I’m going to take issue with your choice of the word “intuition”. People don’t intuit that nothing comes from nothing, they learn it from experience. If I use sleight of hand to ‘magic’ up a piece of candy, an adult will deduce that I had it all along, even if they can’t see how the trick was done, but a small child will simply be delighted with the candy that came from nowhere; their ‘intuition’ is not offended because they have yet to learn that candy appears from nothing in grocery stores.
So, let’s substitute “experience” for “intuition”.
Which then leads to the headline about black swans. For thousands of years everybody in Europe knew that there was no such thing as a black swan. Except … it turns out you can barely move in Western Australia without tripping over the damn things.
You see, experience is a very poor guide to things that are outside your experience. And it turns out that being a semi-evolved ape living at the bottom of a deep gravity well means that a lot of things in the Universe inside a fine-tuned oxygen-nitrogen atmosphere with abundant liquid water are outside our experience.
For example, our best understanding is that spacetime and everything in it, which includes … everything, emerged from nothing which then exploded. Similarly, we’re also pretty sure than the vacuum between the galaxies is simply boiling with matter-antimatter pairs which briefly pop into existence from nothing, ‘borrowing’ the energy to do so from nothing which they pay back when they annihilate each other.

No, something does not necessarily from nothingness. There at least two other alternatives.
The idea of before requires time, but what if time is finite?
Change of all kinds requires time, we can only talk about change when a thing is different at two different moments in time. If something is to be said to have come from nothing then we would require a time when there was nothing and a time when it was. However, according to accepted Physics, space and time are not independent of one another but rather part of a composite spacetime. If the universe itself has an origin then that origin is also the origin of spacetime, time itself begins at that moment and thus there is no before which means that you cannot coherently talk about the things within that universe coming from anything before that time. They exist at time = 0 and there is no time before that to compare them to, no time in which a nothingness can exist.
There is no problem with an infinite past.
There is no more problem with an infinite past than there is with an infinite left; it is simply a matter of your reference point. It is important to understand that even though a line may be infinite, the distance between any two definable points on that line is still finite. Any point in time still happens a finite time before or after now, and the same is true for any other reference point you pick. All an infinite past means is that there is no point at which you can't go any further back in time.

The current moment depends on the previous moment though in time. In a line, the existence of the current point doesn’t depend on an earlier point. So I don’t think the analogy holds. Lastly, can you create an infinitely long line?

@MargaretPierce: Is it dependent on the previous moment? That seems like an assumption  (q.v. the Arrow of Time). But even it is, the assumption that this prevents an infinite sequence is simply a version of Zeno's Paradox.

@MargaretPierce: If the universe is infinite in extent then there any pairing of a point and a direction defines a infinite line. Whether you consider that to "create" a line is a moot point, I think.

“if the universe is infinite in extent” begs the question. Zeno’s paradox doesn’t apply since that’s in reference to an infinite number of infinitesimals between two set points. An infinite past is not in between two fixed points. @Jack Aidley

Cyclic cosmological models might offer a third option, where time itself can be thought of going in cycles. The idea is that a universe starts with the big bang, expands for a while, than contracts for a while, until there is a big crunch, which leads to a new big bang. Since the big crunch/bang kinda resets spacetime time goes back to t=0 and is thus cyclic

Regarding your first option, if you don’t have time, and you have something, by definition you have something from nothing (I’m including “something simply exists” in this umbrella; I realize there’s a subtle distinction around whether something ever didn’t exist), so I’m not sure that option negates OP’s assertion.

@bob No, you don't. There is no "from" capable of happening. To have something from nothingness there must be a time at which there was nothingness. Otherwise there was only ever something.

True but my point (not well expressed) was that this is still a state without an in-universe cause, and I think that is OP’s point.

@bob Yes, it would lack an in-universe cause.

Some warnings about using physics in philosophy. 1) The arrow of time appears to be an emergent property, not fundamental. "Before" is not necessarily fundamental. 2) There are proposed spacetime cosmologies which avoid the need for a t=0. 3) We can coherently talk about before the Universe, tho maybe that just makes our universe a universe.

@Schwern: the existence of other coherent possibilities is irrelevant to the argument, for the claim "something must necessarily come from nothingness" to be true, it must be true in all coherent possibilities. The argument is not that the universe is this way but that it can be.

@JackAidley Things get pretty wild if we allow any possible coherent universe! Spacetime doesn't have to work how it does, and the deeper you go into physics the weirder everything gets. I believe physicists would take issue with the statement "If the universe itself has an origin then that origin is also the origin of spacetime, time itself begins at that moment and thus there is no before which means that you cannot coherently talk about the things within that universe coming from anything before that time" because they coherently talk about things before that time all the time.

C's "explanation" is that something simply exists.  It is an OK alternative to "something comes from nothing"
You don't necessarily need time to have "something", that is your problematic assumption.  Something that has "always existed" only needs to exist always, not that there needs to be an infinite past.
You are correct that we shouldn't use our intuition to resolve this particular problem because it doesn't help because we don't know how universes actually begin, and they likely begin in ways we would find hard to imagine, let alone explain.  We would need more information to actually answer the question definitively.
How existence itself begins is a step beyond that.

OP : "But even if something could be eternal, isn’t it still coming from nothing in that nothing caused it to exist…"
Or nothing stops it. Something lets it be.
On this note, however, I'm told the Hebrew of "fiat lux" is imperative (jussive), not passive.  Otherwise one could consider the view that 'nothing' created the universe by 'letting' it be.

Re. "If C explains B, what explains C? If this can’t continue forever . . ."
Perhaps it could continue forever.  Kant's issue with eternity takes a different tac.  He observes that in infinite time there must be infinite time before now, but infinite time could never end so we would never arrive at now.
From the Critique of Pure Reason, FIRST CONFLICT OF THE TRANSCENDENTAL IDEAS. THESIS.

Granted that the world has no beginning in time; up to every given
moment of time, an eternity must have elapsed, and therewith passed
away an infinite series of successive conditions or states of things
in the world. Now the infinity of a series consists in the fact that
it never can be completed by means of a successive synthesis. It
follows that an infinite series already elapsed is impossible and
that, consequently, a beginning of the world is a necessary condition
of its existence.

Of course, the counter-argument is in the ANTITHESIS.

A beginning is an existence which is preceded by a time in which the
thing does not exist. On the above supposition, it follows that there
must have been a time in which the world did not exist, that is, a
void time. But in a void time the origination of a thing is impossible
...

Kant remarks in the OBSERVATIONS ON THE THIRD ANTINOMY

It is, however, the true stumbling-stone to philosophy, which meets
with unconquerable difficulties in the way of its admitting this kind
of unconditioned causality.

So Kant puts these questions of finitude and infinity aside and the focus becomes apperception and the existential foundation for his ethics, which is the real reason for his analysis.
Modern ideas of the quantum vacuum are neat but still have the problem "What caused the quantum vacuum?"

I can't answer your question, but I can perhaps help you think about it in more detail with that age-old exercise of defining your terms.
"Something" and "nothing" are ill-defined. Let's define them.
What is "nothing"?
In her video What is "Nothing"?, physicist Sabine Hossenfelder offers nine definitions of "nothing", each more refined to distill out any notion of "something". These are based on Leslie and Kuhn's The Mystery of Existance: Why Is There Anything At All?. I prefer the physicist's take as they struggle with this question, too, and have to back it up with rigorous math and observations. You can also listen to Kuhn's own What is Nothing?, either works.
Dr. Hossenfelder's 9 levels of "nothing" are...

No objects.


But that leaves air so...


No air, a vacuum.


But that leaves cosmic rays, neutrinos...


No matter.


But there's still light, magnetism...


No radiation nor other fields. What she calls "the 21st century vacuum".


But quantum fluctuations create virtual particles which can become real particles kicking us back into level 3, so...


No virtual particles, no 21st century vacuum.


But we still have spacetime.


No spacetime, and no laws of nature at all.


There's nothing left from our theories of physics. Where does physics come from? We need another level.


No "non-physical entities". No prime movers. No gods.


We still have math, ideas, platonic ideals, etc.


No abstract concepts.


But it's still possible something can spontaneously come from nothing.


No possibilities.

Any answer is only good to a certain level.
Our levels of "nothing" are also levels of "something". For example, if an answer uses concepts like "time" and "before" that requires the existence of space-time or string theory or whatever cosmology you like... this is level 5 "something". An answer to "how can something come from nothing" which invokes time is only good down to level 5.
Side note: Physicists do discuss what happened before the Big Bang, but that still requires cosmology which is a level 5 "something".
If the answer wants a prime mover, the prime mover is a level 6 "something". If it wants to assert even that 1 + 1 = 2, that's math; that's a level 7 "something". If it wants to assert that given endless "time" (umm...) even the most infinitesimal of possibilities will happen, that's level 8 "something" plus some questions about what we mean by "time" at this level.

But even if something could be eternal, isn’t it still coming from nothing in that nothing caused it to exist…it just exists and that’s it. What’s the difference between this and something just “coming to exist”?

I don't have an answer. All I can say is welcome to level 8.
Pick your turtle to stand on.
Is the absence of anything, not even possibilities, something? Do we need a 10th level that doesn't even have the concept of possibilities?
To have any hope of answering the question, one needs to pick a definition of "nothing" and argue to that, or try to dig down another level.

Has it been everyone's intuition that something cannot come from nothing?
As an aside, I want to address this quite optimistic view of history or even present day.

Throughout the history of time, it has been almost everyone’s intuition that something cannot come from nothing.

I would counter with many "let there be light" style creation myths, spontaneous abiogenesis, straight up belief in magic, and even well into the 20th century the steady-state model of the universe.
One might try to patch over it by saying it didn't come from nothing, it came from an all-powerful prime mover. This just raises more problems. "Almost everyone" has gone with whatever solution to the prime mover problem their faith-leader chose.

The first 4 are a bit repetitive as we currently express a lot of these features by means of particles which in itself are objects. So it's less that they are a different kind of nothing it's more that we didn't fully appreciate how much there still was when we first called with nothing. And up to point 9 you kinda have the question as to whether an observer is required for there to be something. Like a lot of physical forces are interactions between particles so in the absence of particles would these forces still exist and how would we know without looking and thus introducing something.

You ask about the existence of things or events without origin.

As far as we know, since the last 13.4 billion years the only
spontaneous events in our universe are events on the quantum scale,
e.g., the decay of a radioactive isotope.

Concerning an origin of our universe as a whole we cannot say
anything: The concept of time applies only to events within our
universe, not to events beyond our spacetime.
Any thoughts about
events beyond our universe are speculations which exceed the scope of our
scientific concepts of space and time. Notably, speculations about eternal things.

We must be aware of the limits of our philosophical
principles: It’s all very well to say that nothing comes from
nothing. But the meaning of this sentence is questionable. Language can be a trap.




Throughout the history of time, it has been almost everyone’s intuition that something cannot come from nothing. That intuition is so strong that many can’t even imagine this to be false.

I mean Dale M makes a good point that intuitions don't come from nothing, but are largely the result and analysis of experiences.
The problem is our experience is conflicting with regards to something, nothing, creation, destruction and transformation.
Like physics more or less came to the rather resistant idea of conservation of energy. Which argues that energy is neither created nor destroyed, but that the total amount is constant and that everything is just a transformation from one state into another state. However if energy is neither created nor destroyed and if we know of no process by which we can do it, then we can't really reach a state of no energy. It's like standing on top of an indestructible globe trying to get to it's center. We can move in lots of directions but none of that is going to get us any closer to the center of the globe.
On the other hand life itself teaches us about concepts such as "creation", "destruction", "progress" etc. So every life has an origin where it starts and once it's gone there is something that is no longer present so there is some sort of end as well. And from birth to adulthood you most often develop in size and capabilities. So unlike cosmology where energy is a constant, such local examples display some sort of gradient which guides you to it's origin.
So a lot of those questions as to "where did they come" have answers, which lead to more questions and more answers. Prompting the ultimate question as to where does everything that we see come from initially.
And yet another big concept is circles. Cyclic motions are great for understanding things because they allow you to go back and forth between "past" and "future" while staying in the present. They make it possible to look at the whole evolution of a thing ... as a thing. So it's no wonder that our explanation system (physics) makes massive use of circles and periodic structures.
And last but not least our pattern matching system apparently provides us with a prediction system. So essentially we take an initial condition and evolve it according to our experience how things usually evolve (the cyclic stuff has been observed often enough to do that), in order predict what comes next.
Now in that case we start from an axiomatic initial state and evolve this fantasy world further in an attempt to predict the real world.
And in that case we do somewhat create something from nothing as we make up the initial conditions and that fictional universe, that we treat as unrelated but representative of the real one.
However do we really make it up from nothing or isn't it just our current state of perception of the universe as-is? Are we really "creative" or isn't it just a representation of what we experience? So the universe interacting with us rather than we being the root cause of a universe?
But even if for us that would be just an illusion the idea isn't far fetched that someone else could be able to do that or that we and our universe itself could be some powerful entities thought that manifested due to their ideas.
Also as Schwern has touched upon, what actually is "something" or "nothing" is not that obvious to begin with. Like we call a room without people "empty" when there's loads of stuff in it. Even if you remove the stuff there's still loads of air in it that we don't see and thus don't pay attention to. But air is still needed for breathing so we at least can perceive the presence or absence of air. But even if we can't see or perceive things directly they might nonetheless be there and interacting.
So in other words things that happen below our threshold of perception are often considered "nothing", while if they cross our perception threshold they suddenly become "something", so something comes from nothing, except that might just be our illusion due to the fact that we haven't paid attention to the somethings that we couldn't have seen before.
So idk picture yourself looking at a canvas, ans suddenly a blob of paint becomes bigger an bigger until you realize, it's not a canvas it's a window and something is moving towards you.
So "something" can be "created" from "nothing" simply by coming to our attention and moving in domains where it becomes perceptible. So in other words the idea of something being created from nothing and things randomly spawning in and out of existence is not completely alien to us.
However the concept doesn't lend itself well to explaining things and comprehending what's happening. On the contrary it's quite random, so we like to ditch this perception and rather explain it by something that moves continuously an who's trajectory we can measure continuously.
And last but not least, most of our understanding is through the relation and interaction between objects, so the absence of anything to relate to, to react to or to interact is almost incomprehensible because even in the absence of everything you would try to interact and react to yourself, you the observer of the nothing would be something that fills the nothing, so how could you even think about the nothing as more as a space inside the something, which would give it boundaries and features distinct from the something, but sill distinct from the "actual nothing" as well and hence still something.

Explanation is a subjective thing.
When B explains A, that is a relationship in the mind of the explainer between idea B and idea A, not a physical universe relation between physical item B and physical item A.
The next person might not agree that idea B explains idea A. They might want more explanation, or they might be satisfied with no explanation at all.
From this we might see that something (some idea) can come from nothing (no idea), if the person in his/her own mind is satisfied.
As for physical universe causality between A and B, that's the realm of the physicist, and the models they use, and the philosophy of what physics really is. Apparently, even physical universe "nothing" isn't really nothing, but contains dark energy.


Throughout the history of time, it has been almost everyone’s intuition that something cannot come from nothing.

This hasn't been everyones intuition but is the intuition of philosophers. It became everyones intuition because - unlike many philosophical questions - its very easy to understand the question.
The first argument that nothing cannot exist is by Parmenides over 2,500 years ago. As nothing cannot exist, something must exist, and thus everything has come from something.
Later, Aristotle presented five arguments against the existence of the void. In this he was arguing against the atomists who thought the world was simply the motion of atoms in the void. It's the first argument that what we call space is not nothing but actually something. This became obvious with the advent of Einstein's GR because we can see spacetime warp and curve. Your headline question asks:

Does something necessarily come from nothing?

No, because nothing does not exist. There must be something. Thus something necessarily comes from some other thing.


Throughout the history of time, it has been almost everyone’s intuition that something cannot come from nothing. That intuition is so strong that many can’t even imagine this to be false.

That something cannot come from nothing just means that something has to come from some other thing, which makes sense but may not be true.

But wouldn’t the infinite regress of explanation make this necessarily true? If B explains A, what explains B? If C explains B, what explains C? If this can’t continue forever, then C would exist unexplained.

Explanations are produced by humans, so this cannot continue forever. But it might be that the past is infinite so that there would be an infinite regress of causes (not of explanations). And why not?
No one can logically explain the existence of reality precisely because there is nothing outside reality, so there is nothing we could use to explain reality with. The fact is also totally unproblematic except perhaps for metaphysicians.

But if C exists without explanation, doesn’t that mean C comes from nothing? I wager that many people believe that something exists without explanation but not that something comes from nothing. Why?

Because explanations clearly are not causes.

I happen to know the correct answer, but you'll have to read this and not just stop because it sounds strange. Just pretend temporarily, that I know what I'm talking about. It all does make sense.
All of these answers (above) are from what physicist Richard Feynman called, "cocktail party philosophers." He patiently listened to their explanations of why "everything is relative."
A cynical answer to the question in the cocktail party philosopher style might be, "In the beginning, there was nothing. If there was something, then it wasn't the beginning."
But the correct answer is: most (well, a whole lot) of astrophysicists today think the universe not only came from nothing, but that the total sum of all mass and energy of the universe, right now, is zero.
The universe  always was, and always will be, nothing.
"How the eff can that be?", you ask. Well:

Nothing = something + less than nothing.

"Less than nothing" is another name for gravity.


Sounds like somebody's crazy theory, huh? But it is one of the amazing things that Einstein discovered that almost nobody knows about:
Energy stored in the gravitational field is negative mass-energy.
And yes it IS simple to understand! Everything is, you just have to see the simplicity. That's why Feynman won the Nobel Prize. Here, you can understand it, watch:
If instead of being spread out in a sphere 14 billion ly in radius, if all the galaxies were all next to each other in one place, the energy required to push them back out to where they are today would exactly equal the mass-energy of those galaxies.
See, it does make sense! You can understand it! Sure, you can't work all those equations and numbers, but you only need the numbers when you want to build a space telescope or interpret the numbers it sends us.
=== STUFF THAT EXPLAINS IT BUT YOU MIGHT NOT UNDERSTAND:
The reason we can see something when the whole universe is actually nothing, is because we can only see part of the nothing. That makes our point of view asymmetric.
The only part we can see and measure is the stuff at zero distance from us, touching us, right now.
Sure, we can see faraway galaxies — except we can't. We can see only the photons that left those galaxies billions of years ago. And we can only see the photons that touch us right now.
There's a whooole lot more, and it's all just as exciting! But this is already too long, and you wouldn't sit still for it.
